# Trouble identifying resistor with 0.05 tolerance

Tags: resistors

[image]

Having probs identifying this one - and can't find a replacement. Any hints would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I read your resistor to be 101 (divide by 10) = 10.1 ohms and it appears to have a 0.5% tolerance (green band). It's a pretty obscure value so maybe there's a clue on the PCB - is there a component identifier such as "R" followed by a number?

Comment: Not a resistor you see every day - but 10.1 is perfectiy within the E192 series, which matches tolerance of 0.5 %.

Comment: I have seen these quite often in current limiting paths of power supplies, they seem to make absolutely sure that it is at least 10Ω and definitely not less, but a little more doesn't hurt.